# Singular hypersurface containing subvariety of the same degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

When $X$ is a singular hypersurface of prime degree $p$, can it have a subavariety $Y$ of codimension 1 in $X$, i.e., $\dim Y=\dim X-1$ of the same degree $p$ and such that $Y$ is not a linear section of $X$?

Comment: Inside $\mathbb{P}^3$ with homogeneous coordinates $[s,t,u,v]$, consider  the zero scheme $X$ of $u^p - s^{m}v^{m+1},$ where $p=2m+1\geq 5$  This is irreducible and singular along two lines.  Now consider the image $Y$ of the morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^3$ by $[w,z]\mapsto [w^p,w^{p-1}z,w^{m}z^{m+1},z^p].$  This is an irreducible curve of degree $p$ that is contained in no hyperplane.

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to singular hypersurfaces? This can be also true for smooth varieties. For instance, the generic cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ contain a twisted cubic, see [J. Harris,*Algebraic geometry*, Chapter 12].